# Configure redirect URI in Asp.NET Core Azure AD authentication

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, blazor

**How can I tell my app to generate redirect URI with host that I provide? (`foobar.com`)**

Context:

I have Server-Side Blazor Web App, generated from from recent (VS 16.7.5) template, with Azure AD (Single tenant, Work and Schools) authentication.

I use
`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI" Version="3.1.8" />`

I've configured accepted redirected URLs at Az Portal and etc. and I'm able to log in with Azure AD while running my app localy.

[image: Flow]

The redirect URI is sent in query params while being redirected to Azure AD site and it points to website host which is actualy `foobar.azurewebsites.net`.

**How can I tell my app to generate redirect URI with host that I provide? (`foobar.com`)**

The [only solution I've found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63127016/864968) is relevant for former ASP.NET.

`<add key="ida:RedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44326/" />`

Which does not work for in my case.

Comment: I configure this in the portal. For example https : //localhost:44326/authentication/login-callback

Comment: @BrianParker are you talking about `Redirect URIs` available in app registration authentication section?

Comment: Yes. I have two entries one for dev and live

Comment: Is your webapp available from the internet under `azurewebsites.net` domain?

Comment: The link on my profile is single tenant.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to redirect to `foobar.com` and set it both in the portal and in the code, but it still redirects to `foobar.azurewebsites.net`?

Comment: @PamelaPeng yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the Web App sits behind Azure Front Door or an App Gateway, we need to configure the redirect_uri in the /authorize request to be the the Gateway/Front Door's address.

In the code below we override the "OnRedirectToIdentityProvider" event and inject the Front Door/Gateway's address. When I was trying this out I simply hardcoded the address but ideally you'd extract it from the headers that Front Door or App Gateway inject into the request.

This is the code I used when trying to authenticate my Blazor Server App (.net 5) running on an Azure App Service, Protected by Azure AD, running behind Azure Front Door.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ... existing code

    services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new[] { "User.Read" })
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

    services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
            {   
                // Override the redirect_uri
                //  Ideally extract this from config 
                //  Or context.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Host"]
                //  see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-http-headers-protocol#front-door-to-backend

                context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri 
                    = "https://YOUR-FRONT-DOOR-or-APP-GATEWAY/signin-oidc";
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        };
    });

    services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor |
                        ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
        options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
        options.KnownProxies.Clear();
    });

    // ... existing code
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // ... existing code
    
    // Don't forget to add this ...
    app.UseForwardedHeaders();
    
    // ... existing code
}
```

When the code works, the "redirect_uri" param should point to your Front Door/Gateway as shown here.

[image: OAuth Flow]

Hope that helped. ❤️

Comment: Thanks, what version of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI` are you using?

Comment: @pizycki my sample used version 3.1.2 of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI.

Comment: Upgrading Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI to version 5.0.17 works too.

Comment: Any chances to upload your project as a working sample? github for example

Comment: I am using Microsoft.Identity.Web 1.28, which internally uses Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect 5.0.12 and it handles the redirect correctly as long as UseForwarding is set up as described here.  OnRedirectToIdentityProvider code is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround I added a middleware that replaces `redirect_uri` param in callback URL sent to Azure AD.

```cs
public class ResponseInspectMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly AzureADSettings _azureAdSettings;

    public ResponseInspectMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, AzureADSettings azureAdSettings)
    {
        _next = next;
        _azureAdSettings = azureAdSettings;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        await _next(context);

        var headers = context.Response.Headers;
        const string LOCATION_HEADER = "location", REDIRECT_URI_PARAM = "redirect_uri";

        if (context.Response.StatusCode == 302
            && headers.ContainsKey(LOCATION_HEADER)
            && Uri.TryCreate(headers[HeaderNames.Location], UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out var locationHeader))
        {
            Url locationUrl = locationHeader;

            if (locationUrl.ToString().StartsWith(_azureAdSettings.Instance)
                && locationUrl.QueryParams.ContainsKey(REDIRECT_URI_PARAM))
            {
                // Update redirect_url query param

                // Make new redirect url
                var callbackHost = _azureAdSettings?.CallbackHost ?? throw new ArgumentNullException($"{_azureAdSettings.CallbackHost} is not set.");
                var callbackPath = _azureAdSettings?.CallbackPath ?? throw new ArgumentNullException($"{_azureAdSettings.CallbackPath} is not set.");
                Url newRedirectUrl = callbackHost + callbackPath;

                locationUrl.SetQueryParam(REDIRECT_URI_PARAM, newRedirectUrl, isEncoded: false);

                // Swap location headers
                headers.Remove(LOCATION_HEADER);
                headers.Add(LOCATION_HEADER, new StringValues(locationUrl.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you investigated [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50505373/1042934) which is based on the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-5.0#forward-the-scheme-for-linux-and-non-iis-reverse-proxies-1) and discussed in [this](https://seankilleen.com/2020/06/solved-net-core-azure-ad-in-docker-container-incorrectly-uses-an-non-https-redirect-uri/) post? Looks like the case. It is just another approach I suppose.

Comment: @OgnyanDimitrov This is not the same issue. It's not about HTTP/HTTPS, but application using wrong domain as Redirect URL.

Comment: you are correct. I will delete my comment not to lure somebody astray from your solution. I have missed the context.

Comment: Hi @pizycki.
I have the same issue with a .Net Core web app that I want to access through Azure Front Door as it uses Azure AD B2C.
The web app can be accessed from three separate URLs: .azurewebsites.net, .azurefd.net and my custom domain name. And localhost when developing locally.
No matter which one I access from, the redirect_uri is always set to the .azurewebsites.net. I think it is because that is the actual host. But I would like to change it, and I don't know how.